# How can I best manage multiple twitter bootstrap modal dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a web project that makes heavy use of twitter bootstrap modal dialogs. In essence, the user is shown a lot of modal dialogs with forms consecutively. The order of these dialogs is based on the values he provides on each form (= dialog).

How can I best manage the state of the different modals and write filters for the order of them showing up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use this extension to bootstrap to work with modal forms:

https://github.com/Nikku/jquery-bootstrap-scripting

see a demo of the features here:

http://nikku.github.com/jquery-bootstrap-scripting/

Pretty awesome and makes it easy to have modal forms that are effectively wizards (which it sounds like you are describing)

Comment: Thanks. I accepted this, but also wanted to point to http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/turn-any-webform-into-a-powerful-wizard-with-jquery-formtowizard-plugin/ which I used with bootstrap modals.

I made some slight changes to generate the buttons in the modal footer. otherwise it works painlessly.

Answer (score 6):

Lately I have been utilizing the extended Bootstrap Modal below.  Works really well and easy enough to integrate to any bootstrap site

https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/

Demo of the modals options -

http://jschr.github.com/bootstrap-modal/